# Draw a circle boundary?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

In a test for a developer job, I was asked to solve this problem which I had no idea about. Would someone please help me.

Draw a dotted line circle boundary using `void draw(int x, int y)` to draw one point. Use the formula *x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>*. You can use `sqrt` method, but don't use `sin`, `cos` or `tan` etc.

```
Void DrawCircle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius) {…}
```

PS: This is not at all a college assignment, so please reply.

Comment: If it is a job test then you should solve it on your own.

Comment: if the interview is over and you are asking just to gain knowledge  then it is ok . otherwise solve it on your own ..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: If you must use the formula "x^2 + y^2 = r^2", be aware that none of the languages in your tags support the ^ operator. Add some languages that do, and I'm sure you'll get the correct answer!

Comment: i got this job already. This was the only question i couldn't answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wrote a quick code that could solve your problem, but havent tested it.

```
void DrawCircle(int centerX, int centerY, int radius)
{
    int x,y;
    x=-radius;
    while(x < radius)
    {
        y=sqrt(radius*radius-x*x);
        draw(x+centerX,y+centerY);
        y=-y;
        draw(x+centerX,y+centerY);
        x++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that finds the dots on the border of your circle (there's an infinite number of points, the smaller `dDensity` is, the more points you'll get.)

```
double dDensity = 1.0;
double y, x;
for (x = -radius; x <= radius; x += dDensity)
{
   y = sqrt(-pow(x, 2.0f) + pow(r, 2.0f))
   Console.WriteLine("(" + (x+centerX).ToString() + ","
                     + (y+centerY).ToString() + ")");
}
```

That will produce you the Points of which the circle consists of.

'Painting' a circle is a different issue, but thats a good start for you IMO.

Comment: This will only print the values for a *semi*-circle. You must also print the negative square root as in @M.Ivanov's answer!